# can the methods of complex analysis be used to compute this integral?

Tags: complex-analysis

$\int _{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{x^2}{1+x^4}dx$

This was suggested to me.  It is a problem from a PUTMAN exam, if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: PUTMAN exam.  Much easier than the PUTNAM exam!

Comment: @GEdgar I agree, Putnam should be far harder than this. It must be a level 1 question.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use contour integration for this. You can write the function as $$ \frac{x^2}{(x-\sqrt{i})(x-\sqrt{-i})(x+\sqrt{i})(x+\sqrt{-i})}$$ and do a contour integral closed where the contour goes along the real line and then closes in a huge semicircle in the upper half plane (lower would be ok too). The integral along the semicircle is zero since the integrand decays faster than $1/x,$ so you're left with the integral you want.

By Cauchy, you need to compute the residue of each of the poles in the upper half plane, $\sqrt{i}$ and $\sqrt{-i}.$ The first one's residue is $$ \frac{i}{(\sqrt{i}-\sqrt{-i})(\sqrt{i}+\sqrt{i})(\sqrt{i}+\sqrt{-i})} = \frac{i}{(\sqrt{2}i)(2\sqrt{i})(\sqrt{2})} =\frac{1}{4\sqrt{i}}$$
and the second's is similarly $\frac{1}{4\sqrt{-i}}$ so the integral is $$2\pi i\left(\frac{1}{4\sqrt{i}} + \frac{1}{4\sqrt{-i}}\right) = \frac{\pi}{\sqrt{2}} $$

Comment: Whoops, I meant to put $x^2$ in the numerator.  I fixed the question.  Sorry.

Comment: @NażysławZbyłutowicz Ahh, yes I should have probably made this a comment and not an answer. Yes, you can use complex analysis for this, will edit.